# Выравнивание текста таблице по вертикале PrettyTable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, prettytable

Есть вот такая таблица, как сделать чтобы например слово "Подписка" было вертикально по середине ?

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

data = [1, 'Подписка', 'Очень крутая подписка\nочень очень\nну прм очень', 10, '1-100']
mytable = PrettyTable()
mytable.field_names = ["ID", "Услуга", "Описание", "Цена", "Мин\Макс"]
mytable.add_row(data)

print(mytable)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, ответ для потомков)

```
mytable.valign = "m"

'''
"t" = top
"m" = middle
"b" = bottom
'''
```